# Hidden surface determination python

Tags: python, algorithm, graphics, computer-vision

I am given a list of about 100 pose-annotated images (position and orientation of the camera) and a mesh with ~200000 vertices. For each vertex I need to check what the corresponding pixels are (if any) in the images.

The problem that arises however is that when there are occlusions, you end up assigning a pixel to a vertex when the colour camera was not actually observing that vertex - in which case I need to check for any intersections with geometry for every vertex - image pair (about 1M rays that are within the camera frustum).

My current algorithm tries to intersect each ray with each face in the mesh and takes about 800ms for each ray-mesh intersection check - which makes 800000s for the whole run.

I have been looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_surface_determination, Z-buffering and painter's algorithm, but all implementations I could find were very graphics focused and generally in C++ / using OpenGL.

How do I check intersections of so many rays with a mesh in a reasonable run time?